# pandas add new column based on iteration through rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of transactions for a business.

Example dataframe:

```
userid  date        amt start_of_day_balance
123     2017-01-04  10  100.0
123     2017-01-05  20  NaN
123     2017-01-02  30  NaN
123     2017-01-04  40  100.0
```

The start of day balance is not always retrieved (in that case we receive a NaN). But from the moment that we know the start of day balance for any day, we can accurately estimate the balance after each transaction afterwards.

In this example the new column should look as follows:

```
userid  date        amt start_of_day_balance calculated_balance
123     2017-01-04  10  100.0                110
123     2017-01-05  20  NaN                  170
123     2017-01-02  30  NaN                  NaN
123     2017-01-04  40  100.0                150
```

Note that there is no way to tell the exact order of the transactions that occurred on the same day - I'm happy to overlook that in this case.

My question is how to create this new column. Something like:

```
df['calculated_balance'] = df.sort_values(['date']).groupby(['userid'])\
['amt'].cumsum() + df['start_of_day_balance'].min()
```

wouldn't work because of the NaNs.

I also don't want to filter out any transactions that happened before the first recorded start of day balance.

Comment: Set NaNs to 0? That would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that seems to work. I'm not sure how elegant it is.

```
def calc_estimated_balance(g):
    # find the first date which has a start of day balance
    first_date_with_bal = g.loc[g['start_of_day_balance'].first_valid_index(), 'date']

    # only calculate the balance if date is greater than or equal to the date of the first balance
    g['calculated_balance'] = g[g['date'] >= first_date_with_bal]['amt'].cumsum().add(g['start_of_day_balance'].min())
    return g


df = df.sort_values(['date']).groupby(['userid']).apply(calc_estimated_balance)
```